# WAV file sounds from PC to many speakers around LARGE Slot Car & Train Layout-HELP!

Tags: software, speakers, wav

I am building a LARGE train & slot car tracks layout. I have about 50 different WAV file sounds on my Desktop so far. I plan about 14 speakers (right now) top be placed in specific areas - one in the fire station for example. I want to direct specific WAV files to specific channels so that (for example) the fire station sounds come from the fire station speaker ONLY.  Motorcycle sounds will come from the Motorcycle shop speaker. Airguns and engine sounds will come from the Car Mechanics Shop.  General city sounds will be played through 2-4 speakers simultaneously around the city at a lower volume.  I am not concerned with generating WAV files.  I need as many PC card sound outputs as practical and software to direct the sounds to the correct PC prot/external speaker(s).  Triggers can be physical buttons or IR keyboard or perhaps a tablet with layout image communicating with the HP Desktop. I'm very "handy" and my son is a software design engineer, but neither of us have any experience that would help us chose the correct hardware or software. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.  Regards, Vaughn May

Answer (score 1):

There are little MP3 player boards with built-in speaker amplifiers that are around the size of a credit card. You can put the desired sound on a micro SD card or USB stick, connect power and speaker, and trigger the sound by wiring to the "Play" button.  These things are VERY inexpensive and IMHO, practically made for your application.  I searched Ebay for: **mp3 player board** and got hundreds of hits, starting below US$2

[image: example MP3 player/amplifier module]

Comment: Hi Richard,  Thank you for your quick and clear response.  Obviously, we were on the wrong track. Typically over thinking/engineering the challenge.  I have started reviewing these on ebay and will probably buy a couple of different ones to trial and error for best fit. Next will be a "master control" for some of these as the background sounds-should be simple. Then engine sounds triggered by cars breaking light switches around the track.  Much appreciated.  Best regards,  Vaughn